# Search S3 bucket for file extension and size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have multiple files on our S3 bucket with the same file extensions.

I would like to find a way to list all these file extensions with the amount of space they're taking up in our bucket in human readable format.

For example, instead of just listing out all the files with `aws s3 ls s3://ebio-rddata --recursive --human-readable --summarize`

I'd like to list only the file extensions with the total size they're taking:

```
.basedon.peaks.l2inputnormnew.bed.full | total size: 100 GB
.adapterTrim.round2.rmRep.sorted.rmDup.sorted.bam | total size: 200 GB
.logo.svg | total size: 400 MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Python script that will count objects by extension and compute the total size by extension:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

sizes = {}
quantity = {}

for object in s3_resource.Bucket('jstack-a').objects.all():
  if not object.key.endswith('/'):
    extension = object.key.split('.')[-1]
    sizes[extension] = sizes.get(extension, 0) + object.size
    quantity[extension] = quantity.get(extension, 0) + 1
    

for extension, size in sizes.items():
  print(extension, quantity[extension], size)
```

It goes a bit funny if there is an object without an extension.

Comment: Re. "goes a bit funny if there is an object without an extension", you could use `import os`, `_, ext = os.path.splitext(obj.key)`, and `if ext:` to test for the presence of an extension (assuming the object keys are generally compatible with typical filenames/paths).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the SDK for that, with your favorite language and a script to filter out objects recursively for the file formats you want

and then export the list as csv or json whatever you prefer more readable

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea for how to solve this with the awscli and a couple of other command lines tools (grep and awk, freely available on Mac and Linux).

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive \
    | grep -v -E '^.+/$' \
    | awk '{na=split($NF, a, "."); tot[a[na]] += $3; num[a[na]]++;} END {for (e in tot) printf "%15d %6d %s\n", tot[e], num[e], e};'
```

Step by step, `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive` results in output like this:

```
2021-11-24 12:45:39  57600 cat.png
2021-09-29 13:15:48  93651 dog.png
2021-09-29 14:16:06   1448 names.csv
2021-02-15 15:09:56      0 pets/
2021-02-15 15:09:56    135 pets/pets.json
```

Piping that through `grep -v -E '^.+/$'` removes the folders, and the result looks like this:

```
2021-11-24 12:45:39  57600 cat.png
2021-09-29 13:15:48  93651 dog.png
2021-09-29 14:16:06   1448 names.csv
2021-02-15 15:09:56    135 pets/pets.json
```

Finally, the AWK script is called for each line. It splits the last word of each line on the period character (`split($NF, a, ".")`) so it can work out what the file extension is (stored in `a[na]`). It then aggregates the file size by extension in `tot[extension]` and the file count by extension in `num[extension]`. It finally prints out the aggregated file size and file count by extension, which looks something like this:

```
     151251      2 png
       1448      1 csv
        135      1 json
```

You could also solve this fairly simply e.g. in Python using the boto3 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aws cli with pipes (needs gitbash if on windows)

```
aws s3 ls s3://your-bucket-name --recursive | awk '{print $NF ", " $3}' | sed 's/.*\.//' | awk -F, '{a[$1] += $2;} END {for (i in a) printf("%s, %.2f MB\n", i, a[i]/1024/1024);}' | sort -t',' -k2 -nr
```

---

The breakdown :

```
awk '{print $NF ", " $3}'
```

Prints just the file key and size

```
sed 's/.*\.//'
```

Trims output to just the extension and size

```
awk -F, '{a[$1] += $2;} END {for (i in a) printf("%s, %.2f MB\n", i, a[i]/1024/1024);}'
```

Adds up by extension and converts to MB

```
sort -t',' -k2 -nr
```

Sorts the extensions by size

Example Result

[image]