# Pick the most recent file from from AWS S3 for every file type using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a scenario where multiple files are present in an AWS S3 bucket. I need to be able pick the most recent file for every file type based on their last modified date. I can also use the numeric part of the file name as it's indicative of the `hour_yearmonthday` when the file was created.

The following two files needs to be picked as they were the last modified ones -  `File_A_02_20220728.csv` and `File_B_02_20220728.csv`. Any suggestions / snippets on how to do this would be much appreciated.

```
s3://bucket/File_A_00_20220728.csv
s3://bucket/File_A_01_20220728.csv
s3://bucket/File_A_02_20220728.csv 
s3://bucket/File_B_00_20220728.csv
s3://bucket/File_B_01_20220728.csv
s3://bucket/File_B_02_20220728.csv
```

Comment: You should look into boto3, specifically how to [list objects in a bucket](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#list-objects-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket) and ask if you have specific coding questions.

Answer (score 3):

There is no in-built function for Amazon S3 to do this for you.

You would need to use [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) to list the contents of the bucket. Then, use Python logic/lists/dictionaries to identify the files you want. I would recommend:

- From the result set, create a *list* of extensions
- Loop through each extension, finding the latest object for that extension

For an example of grouping by extension, see: [Search S3 bucket for file extension and size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689252/174777)

For an example of selecting the 'latest' object, see: [How to get the latest file of an S3 bucket using Boto3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65304598/174777)